# I am getting this error while installing. how to install gulp in windows?

Tags: npm, gulp

npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gulp v3.9.1 is using graceful-fs v3.0.0 which is deprecated

```
"graceful-fs": "^3.0.0",
```

Current version for graceful-fs is v4.1.3
These are just warnings and will not fail your tasks. I hope gulpjs will upgrade graceful-fs soon.

lodash i guess is a dependency of another dependency.